# how to remove objects from NSMutableArray correctly?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I try to delete items from NSMutableArray in loop. I have an array :(2,3,4,5,6).

```
       int j = [array count];        
       while (array != NULL) {

         NSUInteger g = 0;
    for (int q = 0; q < j; q++) {

        [array removeObjectAtIndex:g];
        }
```

When i set a breakpoint (after first iteration) i got the following:

```
[0]=(id)0x00000000
[1]=(id)0x071421a0(int)3
[2]=(id)0x071421b0(int)4
[3]=(id)0x071421e0(int)5
```

I don't understand how to delete in each iteration a first object. I mean that following it will be first. And why the last one is disappeared every time also? 
Thanks.

Comment: What you are trying to do here ? it looks really messy what you've done here

Comment: Some code depicting how you initialise your array would help. Just tried out your code it works fine ( as expected).

Comment: Why you are not using `[array removeAllObjects]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to delete a collection of objects from an array is to add the objects you want to delete to a separate array, then use that to delete your objects from the primary array in one fell swoop.  There are benefits to this, least of which would be no risk of out-of-bounds, and also the possibility for rolling back since you are essentially removing in a single batch process:

```
int j = [array count];  
NSMutableArray *theseObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int q = 0; q < j; q++)
{
    id thisObject = [array objectAtIndex:q];
    BOOL shouldRemoveThisObject = ...//<--determine if you want to remove this object
    if (shouldRemoveThisObject)
        [theseObjects addObject:thisObject];
}
[array removeObjectsInArray:theseObjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant do as you are trying to do.

`j` is set to 5 (array count) but the array's size is reducing on every iteration. So at one point of time it will try to access ***array out-of-bound***, hence exception and your app will crash.

Instead you need to do as below:

```
while (array.count > 0) {
    NSLog(@"Arr before removal is  : %@",array);
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Arr after removal is  : %@",array);

}
```

If for some other reason you want to remove only first then the above will work.

If you want to remove all the objects at one go: you can use:

```
[array removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: I don't need to delete it all in one moment. I have more difficult code. It doesn't matter. But this code works like mine. The first value is NULL, and last is disappeared.

Comment: @user2032083: no way, the last value will not be disapperting, I am removing the first value. try running the code and check.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to remove all entries. Then you could also call `[myArray removeAllObjects];`

Comment: Haha, really nice thing to catch, I was thinking soomethiing else and wrote dozen lines as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You CAN'T remove objects from NSMutableArray inside a loop. This is because, in that case, array size is changing over each iteration (worst case) and you could try to access to an out of bounds index.

The best option is Jeremy's solution. Keep desired objects on separated array and then remove these objects from the main array, outside of the loop.